# Linux Tomcat startup.sh and shutdown.sh is empty

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat

When using nano or vim to view the content of the tomcat server startup.sh and shutdown.sh scripts, I see that they are empty. There is nothing in them... The corresponding shutdown.bat and startup.bat scripts aren't empty but since this is running on a linux box I can't use those. The scripts are in the /opt/tomcat/bin folder.

How can I restart my tomcat server without those scripts, or how can I get tomcat to create the right scripts?

Comment: try to do `ls -al` and see if your current user has the permission to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up re-installing tomcat and it properly created those scripts again. Looks like someone accidentally wiped them...